# How to generate and sum up a sequence

Tags: bash, shell

Basically, what I'm trying to understand is that how to reassign a variable that was already declared before to a new value.

I want to reassign the variable to a different value in the loop. Then print that sum.

For example in JavaScript,

```
sum = 0;

for... (loop)
sum = sum + start-point; (loop body)

console.log(sum)
```

Now I don't seem to be able to get that in bash.

This is my code in bash

```
echo Enter a number:
read NUMBER
echo Enter a startpoint:
read STARTPOINT
echo Enter how many terms:
read TERMS
sum=0;
for ((n=0;n<$TERMS;n++));
do
   STARTPOINT=$((STARTPOINT + NUMBER))
   sum=$(($sum + $STARTPOINT))
        echo $STARTPOINT
        echo $sum
done
```

All the code is correct except the sum part, and because of it the code doesn't run properly. if I remove that part, it works fine. I just need to sum the outputs of the variable **STARTPOINT**.

### Example

**Input**

```
NUMBER = 3 (means to increment 3 in the startpoint)
STARTPOINT = 2
TERMS = 5 (means to add 3 to 2 five times)
```

**Expected output**

```
5
8
11
14
17
```

And the part that I am having difficulty with is how to add all these numbers, when all added, it should print 55.

Comment: You code is not very elegant but works for me. Can you add an example input, expected output, and actual output / error message?

Comment: Should `sum` start at `STARTPOINT` and shouldn't `NUMBER` be added to `sum` in each iteration?

Comment: Forgot $? STARTPOINT=$(($STARTPOINT + $NUMBER))

Comment: The expected output would be 
5
8
11
14
17

And the part that I am having difficulty with is how to add all these numbers, when all added, it should print 55.

Comment: @etsuhisa it works without that as well, donno why.

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you please fix the code fully, I'm not quite getting your point, sorry about that. I'm just new in coding

Comment: @Howdypaudy I just used the names of your variables as input since I didn't know what you expected out of the program. Now that you've shared that with us, my question is answered (with "no"). Socowi's answer looks spot on.

Comment: @Socowi, thank you, let me see if I can change the title of the question. My apologies, I'm new to bash as well as programming so my terminology can be off sometimes. Appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I changed your variable names to be lowercase. This is the conventional  naming scheme in bash to avoid accidental name collisions with built-in variables and environment variables.

If I understood correctly, you want to build the following sequence and also sum it up:

`startpoint + 1*number` +  `startpoint + 2*number` + ... + `startpoint+ term*number`

In that case you should *not* change `startpoint` inside your loop. Use another variable to store the result of `startpoint + n*number`.

```
startpoint=2 number=3 terms=5 sum=0
echo "$terms times increment $startpoint by $number:"
for ((n=1; n<=terms; n++));
do
  ((addend = startpoint + n*number))
  echo "$addend"
  ((sum += addend))
done
echo "The sum is $sum"
```

However, instead of using a slow loop you could printing the sequence using `seq` and then calculate its sum using the closed formula for [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

```
startpoint=2 number=3 terms=5
seq $((startpoint+number)) $number $((startpoint+terms*number))
((sum = terms*startpoint + terms*(terms+1)/2 * number))
echo "The sum is $sum"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate your help. This works perfectly.